# Can I execute code that is stored in Azure DevOps repo remotely

Tags: git, azure-devops, npx

I am new to Azure DevOps, Git and using repositories for version control. I researched and saw that it may be possible to run code that is stored in a Github repo by using npx commands [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/npm-execute-code-from-a-remote-github-branch-with-npx), but this requires setup that wasn't explained. Is it possible to programmatically (C#/ASP.NET or Typescript/Angular 7) and remotely execute code that is stored in a repository? This is so that front end users of a web app can run a service with the click of a button without downloading the files to specific folders on their local machines.

More specifically this is for an Indexer service that we currently have in Azure that is being run like this:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            string SearchServiceName = "serviceName";
            string SearchServiceAdminApiKey = "adminKey";

            var searchService = new SearchServiceClient(
                SearchServiceName, credentials: new SearchCredentials(SearchServiceAdminApiKey));

            searchService.Indexers.Run("nameOfIndexer");
        }
```

This indexes documents so that our search service can find them. However it doesn't do everything we need it to, hence the need to run the code in the repository instead. Is it possible to programmatically run the code that is in the repo?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you want to run this from an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Comment: @NapoleonIkeJones so that users won't have to download the files to their machines -- they click the button and the code is ran remotely which performs the service

Comment: I don't think Azure DevOps is the correct place for this.  Take a look at Azure Functions with an HTTP trigger.

Comment: The link you point to simply uses a bit of obfuscation to get the user to download the code from the repo then to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must download/clone it and run it 'locally'.